# Share typed model between nodejs and angular2 client with npm

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, package

I have an idea to use one `model` project for both NodeJS server backend (written in typescript) and Angular2/Ionic2 client application.

I have just very little experience of working with typescript and Angular2 and I was unable to find any guide for doing such a `packaging` and using such a module on a both sides.

Model project would be residing on git repo and installed with `npm` on both sides --that's what I was able to do, to share (incomplete) `package` with the npm.

Can you guide me, please? I need a configuration steps to make this logicless module usable on NodeJS and client Angular2 together.

Comment: What is the purpose of the model?  What do you want it to do on a server and on a client?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model